# Cannot set PeriodicTask schedule

Tags: django, django-celery-beat

I use Django Celery Beat in order to manage periodic tasks.

Here, I create a periodic task and set it some schedule:

```py
        new_instance = PeriodicTask.objects.create(
            name=f'L1 Synchonisation created at {timezone.now()}',
            task='integrations.tasks.test_task',
        )
        schedule, _ = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(
            every=self.every,
            period=self.period
        )
        new_instance.interval = schedule
        print(new_instance.interval)  # new_instance.interval is not None
        new_instance.save()
        print(new_instance.interval)  # None
        new_instance.refresh_from_db()
        print(new_instance.interval)  # None
```

My question is, why does `new_instance.interval` become `None` and how do I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I cannot change the schedule of a `PeriodicTask`. It can only be set at the same time `PeriodicTask` is instantiated:

```py
        schedule, _ = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(
            every=self.every,
            period=self.period
        )
        new_instance = PeriodicTask.objects.create(
            name=f'L1 Synchonisation created at {timezone.now()}',
            task='integrations.tasks.test_task',
            interval=schedule,
        )
        print(new_instance.interval)  # new_instance.interval is not None
        new_instance.refresh_from_db()
        print(new_instance.interval)  # new_instance.interval is not None
```